# How do I load a my Java applet on a Click event?

Tags: java, javascript, security, asp-classic, applet

I have a `div` where I load a Java applet, but the new version of Java is giving an unsigned certificate error:

[image: Error]

I would like to know if I can restrict the loading of my Java applet (`DeployJava.RunApplet`), currently instantiated while the page is loaded, to only load when user clicks the *View in 3D* button?

Applet loading code:

```
<div id="appletContainer" runat="server" style="width:(document.body.clientWidth - 270);height:300" clientidmode="Static">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var showCI = 0;
        if (document.getElementById("hdnHas3D").value == "1" && !isAppleMobile()) {
            var J3DStyleID = document.getElementById("hdn3DStyleID").value;
            var code = "com.wirefusion.player.AppletPlayer";
            var archiveList = "Some achive List";
            var width = document.body.clientWidth - 270;
            var height = 300;

            var attributes = {
                id: "appletContainerX",
                name: J3DStyleID,
                code: code,
                codebase: ".",
                width: width,
                height: height,
                mayscript: "true"
            };
            var parameters = {
                progressFunc: "handleAppletProgress",
                archive: archiveList,
                java_arguments: "-Xmx200m",
                regid: "6050-25",
                resourcefolder: "/RichContent/3D_Vehicles/J3D/Vehicles/" + J3DStyleID + "/",
                preloadfile: J3DStyleID + ".jar",
                environmentType: "WEBSITE",
                environmentWidth: width,
                environmentHeight: height,
                groupsXMLFile: "../../Resources/groups.xml",
                vehicleXMLFile: J3DStyleID + ".xml"
            };
            var version = '1.6.0_20';
            if (deployJava.versionCheck(version + '+')) {
                docWriteWrapper(function () {
                    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
                });
            } else {
                if (document.getElementById("iframeContainer").style.display != "none") {
                    alert("Unable to load Interactive mode");
                    showCI = 1;

                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: BTW - why only 3 out of 13 accepted [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/621898/maybe2013?tab=questions&sort=newest), despite answers for *every* question?

Comment: Ok, i will mark the best suited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't include the regular `<applet>` (or `<object>`) tag in your HTML. Instead [follow this tutorial](http://kaioa.com/node/21)  on how to do dynamically add it to your page, using JavaScript.

HTML 4

```
function loadApplet(code,codebase,width,height,alt){
    var placeholder=document.getElementById('placeholder');
    if(window.opera){
        placeholder.innerHTML='<applet code="'+code+'" codebase="'+codebase+'" width="'+width+'" height="'+height+'" alt="'+alt+'"></applet>';
    }else{
        var a=document.createElement('applet');
        a.setAttribute('code',code);
        a.setAttribute('codebase',codebase);
        a.setAttribute('width',width);
        a.setAttribute('height',height);
        a.setAttribute('alt',alt);
        placeholder.appendChild(a);
    }
}
```

HTML 5

```
function loadApplet(code,codebase,width,height,alt){
    var placeholder=document.getElementById('placeholder');
    var a = document.createElement('object');
    a.setAttribute('type','application/x-java-applet');
    a.setAttribute('width',width);
    a.setAttribute('height',height);
    a.setAttribute('alt',alt);
    
    var codeParam = document.createElement('param');
    codeParam.setAttribute('name','code');
    codeParam.setAttribute('value',code);
    a.appendChild(codeParam);

    var codebaseParam = document.createElement('param');
    codebaseParam.setAttribute('name','codebase');
    codebaseParam.setAttribute('value',codebase);
    a.appendChild(codebaseParam);

    placeholder.appendChild(a);
}
```

In your HTML create a placeholder `DIV`, i.e. where you want to it to be loaded into, and a link to load your applet. You will need to customise the values in the load link to your values of the Applet.

```
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<input type="button" value="Load Applet" onclick="loadApplet('TestApplet.class','.','200','300','demo applet')" />
```

The linked tutorial explains more about how to make it pretty. The code above is just simply the concept.

---

### Update since modification of question

Your code appears to load the applet using JavaScript already. The problem is the script is being run as soon as the page is loaded and not when the user clicks on the *View in 3D* button.

To prevent it running immediately, you can wrap the loader code in a function called `loadApplet`. So explained in pseudo code:

```
function loadApplet() {
    // Your existing applet loading code
}
```

So using your included source code, I have wrapped it with a function, which will prevent it running when your page is loaded.

```
<div id="appletContainer" runat="server" style="width:(document.body.clientWidth - 270);height:300" clientidmode="Static">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Wrap your code with a function called loadApplet
        function loadApplet() {
            // Your applet loading code:
            var showCI = 0;                                        
            if (document.getElementById("hdnHas3D").value == "1" && !isAppleMobile()) {
                var J3DStyleID = document.getElementById("hdn3DStyleID").value;
                var code = "com.wirefusion.player.AppletPlayer";
                var archiveList = "Some achive List";                                         
                var width = document.body.clientWidth - 270;
                var height = 300; 

                var attributes = {
                    id: "appletContainerX",
                    name: J3DStyleID,
                    code: code,
                    codebase: ".",
                    width: width,
                    height: height,
                    mayscript: "true"
                };
                var parameters = {
                    progressFunc: "handleAppletProgress",
                    archive: archiveList,
                    java_arguments: "-Xmx200m",
                    regid: "6050-25",                                                
                    resourcefolder: "/RichContent/3D_Vehicles/J3D/Vehicles/" + J3DStyleID + "/",
                    preloadfile: J3DStyleID + ".jar",
                    environmentType: "WEBSITE",
                    environmentWidth: width,
                    environmentHeight: height,
                    groupsXMLFile: "../../Resources/groups.xml",
                    vehicleXMLFile: J3DStyleID + ".xml"
                };
                var version = '1.6.0_20'; 
                if (deployJava.versionCheck(version + '+')) {
                    docWriteWrapper(function () {
                        deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
                    });                                               
                } else {
                    if (document.getElementById("iframeContainer").style.display != "none") {
                        alert("Unable to load Interactive mode");
                        showCI = 1;

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Then to your *View in 3D* element you must add an `onclick` attribute calling the `loadApplet()` function. For example:

```
<input type="button" value="Show in 3D" onclick="loadApplet()" />
```

Note: It may be the case that your *View in 3D* button already has an `onclick` attribute wired to a function that brings your applet into view, in which case you would still want this to be called after your load function. I have used `showApplet()` as an example, this is most likely different for you.

```
<input type="button" value="Show in 3D" onclick="loadApplet(); showApplet();" />
```

If you provide the code for your *Show in 3D* button, I can better assist you here.

Comment: @Maybe2013 You're welcome. If you find it useful please remember to upvote, if it answers your question please mark it as the answer. If you have any issues, let me know in the comments of this answer and I can try help you. Good luck.

Comment: The [`applet` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_applet.asp) is deprecated and not supported in HTML5; the [`object` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp) should be used instead.

Comment: Note that `TestApplet.class` (the file name) should ultimately be `TestApplet` (the fully qualified class name).  +1 for codebase & alt usage.

Comment: @Vulcan Good point, I have updated with code to support creating using the `object` syntax.

Comment: thanks.. but this is asp.net and deplayJava.js is used for Running Applet. Can i not load applet at page load instead of the button click "view in 3d" ?

Comment: @Maybe2013 Please see the update I have added to the question. I hope you can follow what I have changed about your code. If you have any questions or problems let me know. I can create a chat room on stackoverflow if you want to discuss it in realtime.

Comment: Thanks for your time.I am a newbie regarding these,and i am following what you have written.

Comment: @Maybe2013 not a problem, happy to help. Just let me know

Comment: @Maybe2013 If it helps you can chat here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31175/discussion-between-scott-maybe2013